# How to update composer.json from Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

So I'm building a Laravel package and there is a special features that requires updating composer by adding a psr-4 namespace which points to a directory in Laravel base path.

I have tried this so far but doesn't work.

```
$loader = include(base_path('vendor/autoload.php')); 

$loader->add('Classes\Weather', base_path('modules'));
```

Later:

```
$weather = new Classes\Weather\WeatherSite();
```

Comment: Are you sole it? I have this problem too

Comment: Not yet. Still looking for a way out.

Comment: This is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545096/how-to-manually-add-classloader-in-laravel-5

Comment: I see. Let's keep waiting for an answer. I have been googling

Answer (score 1):

You might check this thread, which gives some solutions:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1906#issuecomment-51632453

Answer (score 1):

After several trials and going through Composer documentation, I was able to come up with this which works:

NB: The reason why I needed this solution is to enable me add a Psr4 path automatically from a Laravel package without manually adding a specific path required in the package manually in composer.json

Add this in the boot method of your package service provider , mine is `DigitlimitModuleServiceProvider`

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DigitlimitModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function boot()
     {
        $autoload = require base_path('vendor/autoload.php');
        $autoload->addPsr4('Digitlimit\\Module\\',  base_path('modules'));
        $autoload->register();

        if(!file_exists(base_path('modules'))){
           \File::makeDirectory(base_path('modules'));
           //works as long as there is permission
        }
     }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```